# Let p ∈ P be an odd prime. Show that the sum of the legendre symbol (a/p) for 0<a<p is 0.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

First I note that $(a/p)$ cannot equal 0 because $0<a<p$.

I have verified the statement for p =3, 5, and 7 by applying the formula: $$(a/p) = a^{(p-1)/2} mod(p)$$

$$3:  1 - 1 = 0$$
$$5:  1 - 1 - 1 + 1 = 0$$
$$7:  1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 - 1 = 0$$

I have made the following observation:

The exponent $(p-1)/2 = \phi(p)/2$

This can be relevant when calculating the legendre symbol, for example when calculating $(4/7)$ we have $[4]_{7}^{3} = [2]_{7}^{6} = [1]_{7}$.

While I have been able to validate these cases I don't see a pattern or insight that can be used to show that the relation must be true.

Comment: Presumably you already have proved there are as many quadratic residues as there are non-residues. That finishes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The sum of the Legendre symbols is zero if and only if there are an equal number of quadratic and quadratic non-residues.

Can you find a bijection between the set of residues and non-residues?